# How to convert a string into hexadecimal in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, byte

I've found many posts on StackOverflow which have covered this question in C++, C# and other languages, but none with Shell.

Using Bash/Shell, how do I convert a random `String` into a `byte array`?

I tried:

```
echo "some string" | xxd -r -p
```

but it didn't work.

I basically want a byte output - e.g. `)?e?GV??vY?Ge?#G`

Comment: A byte array with what encoding?

Comment: Byte output of "some string" is "some string".

Comment: @alecrosic : How does the example output you provided, relate to the input?

Answer (score 33):

If you want to get the hex values of some string, then this works:

```sh
$ echo "testing some values"$'\157' | xxd
0000000: 7465 7374 696e 6720 736f 6d65 2076 616c  testing some val
0000010: 7565 736f 0a                             ueso.
```

If you just need the "plain" string:

```sh
$ echo "testing some values"$'\157' | xxd -p
74657374696e6720736f6d652076616c7565736f0a
```

If you need to "reverse" an **hex** string, you do:

```sh
$ echo "74657374696e6720736f6d652076616c7565736f0a" | xxd -r -p
testing some valueso
```

If what you need is the character representation (not hex), you could do:

```sh
$ echo "testing:"$'\001\011\n\bend test'  | od -vAn -tcx1
  t   e   s   t   i   n   g   : 001  \t  \n  \b   e   n   d    
 74  65  73  74  69  6e  67  3a  01  09  0a  08  65  6e  64  20
  t   e   s   t  \n
 74  65  73  74  0a
```

Or:

```sh
$ echo "testing:"$'\001\011\n\bend test'  | od -vAn -tax1
  t   e   s   t   i   n   g   : soh  ht  nl  bs   e   n   d  sp
 74  65  73  74  69  6e  67  3a  01  09  0a  08  65  6e  64  20
  t   e   s   t  nl
 74  65  73  74  0a
```

Comment: Can I ask why did you add "o" at the end ($'\157')? I thought these are some flags to this command and spent like 2 hours trying to figure out where is this extra "o" comming from.

Comment: Thank you for your answer regardless. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to convert hex string to bytes. xxd needs a starting point (since it is used to patch binary files and such)

```
string="626c610a"
echo "0: $string" | xxd -r
```

xxd will also silently skip any invalid hex, so check your data if you get empty output.